# Measuring the magnitude of the magnetic field of a single electron due to its spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, electrons, measurement-problem

Is it possible to measure the magnitude of the magnetic field of a single electron due to its spin? The electron's intrinsic magnetic field is not dependent upon the amount of energy it has does it? Does this require a SQUID, a Superconducting Quantum Interference Device? What published papers or experiments have been done to answer this question?

Comment: Second time a "single electron". What do You mean, a free electron or a single electron?

Comment: I realized that I had asked the wrong thing, "spin",  in the question involving a single electron I had asked before. I meant magnetic field magnitude, hence I made this question.

I mean a free electron by itself, blocking all other external electric & magnetic fields, lets say by making a Faraday cage or something.

Comment: Why don't You edit Your question accordingly? And: Spin is not the wrong thing! What else than the magnetic field due to spin  was measured in Stern-Gerlach-experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [publication](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2007/11/071101144942.htm) measures single electrons:

*Researchers at the Delft University of Technology's Kavli Institute of Nanoscience and the Foundation for Fundamental Research on Matter (FOM) have succeeded in controlling the spin of a single electron merely by using electric fields. This clears the way for a much simpler realization of the building blocks of a (future) super-fast quantum computer.*

I suppose they have taken as given the value of the electron magnetic field, but the apparatus could be used to measure it, I am sure.