# How can we know about particle spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, subatomic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one experimentally determine chirality, helicity and spin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/how-does-one-experimentally-determine-chirality-helicity-and-spin)

This is a rough quite from Hawking:

"An elementary particle with 0 spin looks the same no matter what direction. A particle with spin-1 looks the same only after a full revolution (360degrees) in spin. A particle with spin-2 looks the same after a half revolution (180degrees)."

How do we know this when we can't even see the particles?
How do we measure spin?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11197/2451