# Which phenomenon is related to the spin of photons?

Tags: photons, electrons, spin-models

The phenomenon of the deflection of a moving electron in a magnetic field is related to the electrons spin. From which phenomenon it is concluded, that photons have a spin?

Comment: I'm pretty sure polarization is the result, but I could be wrong. I do know that spin is inferred from the selection rules between energy levels in atoms (so to be conserved the the photon must carry it off)

Comment: I think https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73942/how-do-we-know-photons-have-spin-1?rq=1 would give an appropriate explanation.

Comment: *"The phenomenon of the deflection of a moving electron in a magnetic field is related to the electrons spin."* Really? How do you figure that?

Comment: @dmckee Particles with spin can possess a magnetic dipole moment, just like a rotating electrically charged body in classical electrodynamics. These magnetic moments can be experimentally observed in several ways, e.g. by the deflection of particles by inhomogeneous magnetic fields in a Stern–Gerlach experiment, or by measuring the magnetic fields generated by the particles themselves.

Comment: Then you need an edit. Because "the deflection of a moving electron in a magnetic field" will typically be read as being due to the Lorentz force as (a) that contribution is vastly dominate unless the velocity is trivial and (b) the effect exploited in the Stern-Gerlach experiments does not require that the subject particles be moving (the experiment requires it for practical reasons, but the dipole-gradient force does not).

Comment: Of course Stern-Gerlach experiments are not done on particles with a net charge because of the Lorentz effect dominates and because the beam has some non-trivial envelope and gets spread all over by the inhomogeneous field.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210671/66086).