# What are the ways of finding the spin of a particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-spin

How many ways are there for this mission? Any article about that on the internet. I heard about TODAI made a reprogrammable quantum computer.

Any more ideas are welcome

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11197/2451 and links therein.