# Is chirality an intrinsic property of elementary fermions?

Tags: fermions, elementary-particles, chirality

Is it the case that chirality is an intrinsic property of elementary fermions? I mean, is it the case that all electrons have left handed chirality while all positrons have right handed chirality? And is it possible to measure the chirality of a particle?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246637/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161170/50583

Answer (score 2):

No, massive particles necessarily have components corresponding to both left-handed and right-handed chirality.
["Only left-handed fermions and right-handed antifermions interact with the weak interaction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)#Chiral_theories), but right-handed Fermions do exist and chirality can change dynamically.

Regarding measurability, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161170/how-can-we-measure-chirality-in-experiments) question.