# How does an electron qubit work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-information

Imagine a qubit, whose physical support is an electron.
If its information is the spin, how could we change the spin of the electron?
It can have two spins, so I thinks that to change it, you have to make it absorb a photon.

Also, and most importantly, how do you measure its spin not only once, but several times? possibly without altering the electrons spin?

And also, how do you create entangled electrons?

Thank you for your answer and thank you for your time.

Comment: This is a bunch of very different questions. For how to measure the spin of an electron see [this related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8188/58382). You do not need to have it "absorbe a photon", a magnetic field is enough. To "measure the spin several times" you just do the measurement several times (??). Any measurement will alter the state of the spin, unless the spin state is initially in an eigenstate of the measurement.

Comment: How to create entangled electrons is whole different story, and should probably be a question of its own. There are several different ways, depending on the context and experimental architecture that is being used.